# Xamarin.Forms Image not showing from Source

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, imagesource

I'm using fake Api for testing app.The Api is on this link: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`. I connect my App, get all photos and add to CollectionView. Everything work perfectly fine but images are not showing.Here is my code:

```
    <Grid>
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
            <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
             Command="{Binding LoadRefreshCommand}">
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto}" >
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid Padding="0,0,5,0" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>

                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CurrentPage}, Path=BindingContext.LoadPhotosCommand}" />
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Image  Source="{Binding Url}" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
                                <Frame HasShadow="False" VerticalOptions="Center"  Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                                </Frame>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" BorderColor="#07987f" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="#eeeeee">
                <StackLayout>
                    <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></ActivityIndicator>
                    <Label TextColor="#07987f" Text="Loading Data, Please Wait..." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the image i get from debug app:

[image]

What can be the problem or all images are blank.
Also i get this in the console:

```
[0:] HTTP Request: Could not retrieve https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97, status code Gone
[0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97
```

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97" returns a 304 status code

Comment: @Jason what is 304 not modified meaning?

Comment: @Jason any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Use a different service.  It doesn't sound like the image urls being returned are behaving properly

Comment: @Jason image url looking good

Comment: the messages received on the console would indicate otherwise.

Comment: @Jason i receive all photos from the Api and just pass the url to the Image source. It is simple i open the url in the browser and it is fine. Give some suggestion code. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why source makes a reading problem. This is how i fix it:

1. Just change the following options and it should work with https too.
2. Android Options => Advanced
3. HttpClient implementation = Set to "Managed" option value
4. SSL/TLS implementation = set to "Native TLS 1.2+" option value